# Type of BLOB files in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, blob

What are the type of files that can be categorize as BLOB files in SharePoint Content database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BLOB (Binary Large Object) is a large object data type in the database
>   system. BLOB could store a large chunk of data, document types and
>   even media files like audio or video files. BLOB fields allocate space
>   only whenever the content in the field is utilized. BLOB allocates
>   spaces in Giga Bytes. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414551/what-is-it-exactly-a-blob-in-a-dbms-context)

So basically, everything you store in SharePoint (documents, images, video, other files) will count as BLOB